# How to transfer type parameters between types?

Tags: java, generics, gson, retrofit

While using `retrofit` with `Gson` I came across a situation where the provided type and the final types were different but require the same type parameter.

We have this method in a service:

```
@GET("awesome")
AwesomeCall<AwesomeObject> get();
```

And I want `AwesomeCall` to return an `AwesomeResult` which contains the relevant `AwesomeObject` or an error (bearing in mind that this 'awesome' API ignores HTTP and always returns 200, only to give an error object instead of our expected `AwesomeObject`)

What I want is for retrofit to parse `AwesomeResult` and make `AwesomeCall` return such object if there is no problem with the Request.

The problem I had is that retrofit only provides me with the return type of the service, but I needed to get a different object.

PS: This was done so that the service doesn't have any references to retrofit objects that would leak into higher levels in the code.

Answer (score 3):

So, after some digging into the abysm of reflexion I discovered that you can implement `ParameterizedType` (since it's an interface) and use that to generate a different call from retrofit.

Inside my `CallAdapter.Factory` implementation I created this type:

```
private static class AwesomeResponseType implements ParameterizedType {
    private final Type innerType;

    public BrainResponseType(Type innerType) {
        this.innerType = innerType;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {innerType};
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return AwesomeResponse.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and when creating the adapter I inject the inner type like this:

```
final Type innerType = getParameterUpperBound(0, (ParameterizedType) returnType);
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = new AwesomeResponseType(innerType);
```

and used the `parameterizedType` to create a custom `CallAdapter` like this:

```
private static class AwesomeCallAdapter<T> implements CallAdapter<AwesomeCall<?>> {

    private final Type responseType;

    private AwesomeCallAdapter(Type responseType) {
        this.responseType = responseType;
    }

    @Override
    public Type responseType() {
        return responseType;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <R> AwesomeCall<T> adapt(Call<R> call) {
        return new AwesomeCall<>((Call<AwesomeResponse<T>>)call);
    }

}
```

The `AwesomeCall` can now happily process a call that expects an AwesomeResponse:

```
public class AwesomeCall<T> {
    private final Call<AwesomeResponse<T>> call;

    public AwesomeCall(Call<AwesomeResponse<T>> call) {
        this.call = call;
    }

    public AwesomeResponse<T> execute() throws IOException {
        Response<BrainResponse<T>> response = call.execute();
        return response.isSuccessful() ? response.body() : errorResponseFrom(response);
    }

    private AwesomeResponse<T> errorResponseFrom(Response<AwesomeResponse<T>> response) {
        return new AwesomeResponse<>(null, new AwesomeError(response.message()));
    }

}
```

If you are using Guava, I believe you don't have to implement `ParameterizedType`. `TypeToken` has an API to do this:

```
TypeToken.of(AwesomeResponse.class).where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, innerType).getType();
```

But sadly, the `TypeToken` in Gson doesn't support that functionality :(